# Logging from Azure Function Java only complete on cold start

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app, spring-cloud-function

I'm not sure if it's a bug or some obscure setting I haven't found yet but I am getting different log behaviours for identical calling parameters. I set up a script to call an endpoint every 3 seconds with the same payload. On first call where there is a cold start I see:

```
2020-03-05 22:04:13.262 Handler processing a request for: transform
2020-03-05 22:04:21.840 Handler processing a request for: transform
2020-03-05 22:04:21.840 Received message: Message(<snip>)
2020-03-05 22:04:21.841 Successful metrics: 1 Unsuccessful metrics: 0
2020-03-05 22:04:22.497 Function "transform" (Id: 98d6e618-637f-4104-81b5-a67f2701bb81) invoked by Java Worker
```

On several subsequent calls I just see:

```
2020-03-05 22:04:24.216 Handler processing a request for: transform
2020-03-05 22:04:24.217 Function "transform" (Id: c1f4f7d0-b36e-4be4-bd38-aeebc5117900) invoked by Java Worker
```

Here's my host.json:

```
{
"version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00",
  "extensionBundle": {
  "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  },
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Host.Results": "Trace",
      "Function": "Warning",
      "Function.transform.User": "Information",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Trace"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond": 50
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What could be the problem? The sampling settings did not affect the behaviour. The problem is that the messages such as "Received message..." are the important ones.

I also looked in the kudu app dump for the function and the logging is also incomplete there.

Comment: I believe you or someone else just commented here about the same - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues/437#issuecomment-594914426. Please consider raising a separate issue for that

Comment: Ok thanks: no that was not me but does seem to match my problem perfectly. I can't figure out from the text whether the bug addresses the problem or not but I can create a new one.